# Is there a way to hide warnings within cocoapods in AppCode?

Tags: cocoapods, appcode

Is there a way to hide warnings within cocoapods in the AppCode build log? I like seeing warnings in my code but the massive number of warnings that result from building my included cocoapods make it hard to see my warnings. It would be nice if I could configure AppCode to hide warnings that come from building source in the Pods directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

My Podfile starts with:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```